# RxJs - What is the proper pattern/way to create an Observable array of Observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, publish-subscribe

Am fairly new to RxJs, and trying to wrap my head around what the proper pattern is to simply create an Observable array of Observables.

I want to retrieve a list of User's Posts. The Posts themselves should be Observables, and I want to keep them all in an Observable array, so that when the array changes the calling code should be notified and update anything subscribed to the post "list". This is simple enough, but I also would like each of the Posts to be Observables, so if I retrieve a specific posts[i] from it, I should also be able to subscribe to these individual objects. 
What is the proper way to do this?

Am using Angular 9, I have:

```
public getPosts(): Observable<Array<Post>> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) = {
        let posts: Observable<Array<Post>> = new Observable<Array<Post>>();
        this.get<Array<Post>>('posts').subscribe(r => {
            posts = from(r);
            return resolve(posts);
        });
    });
}
```

This gives me an `Observable<Array<Post>>`, but how should I create an `Observable<Array<Observable<Post>>>`?
Is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: really unclear how you're intending to go about this.... the http client makes a single request for the `posts` at that point in time. it is not notified of changes without you having to request again.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Generally speaking, this would be an anti-pattern. Creating nested observables is never a good idea in terms of readability and maintainability. There are loads of built-in operators in rxjs exists just for flatten nested observables to prevent it from becoming a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Xinan, it makes sense... I'm just trying to determine how to retrieve a single Observable<Post> each time I need one, without recreating a new Observable<Post> anytime any client requests one (it should return the existing Observable<Post>, if it exists), so I think I just need to cache or store the existing Observable<Post> objects when they are created, and return those, or otherwise create a new one...

Answer (score 1):

It all comes to convenience, if your server serves you differential data of what changed in post, then go ahead and create `Observable<Observable<Post>[]>`.

---

In your post, however, there are multiple problems. You cannot mix `Observables` with `Promises`. The method `getPosts` will return only the first post you get from API.

---

This is the solution ask for, but I am not sure, it is what you actually wanted...

```
public getPosts(): Observable<Array<Observable<Post>>> {
  return this.get('posts').pipe(
    switchMap(posts => combineLatest(
      posts.map(post => this.get('post', post.id))
    )),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution makes sense, I think, but as I understand it it would be making a request for every single post at the time of requesting all posts (to turn them all into Observables using this.get('post, post.id))... shouldn't that be avoidable, since I already have the full array of posts? Isn't there a way to turn them each into Observables without having to re-request them all from the server? Or is this not a preferred way to do things with RxJs?

Answer (score 1):

it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here, but you might want something more like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class PostService {
  // private replay subject will cache one value
  private postSource = new ReplaySubject<Post[]>(1)
  // public list of posts observable
  posts$ = this.postSource.asObservable();
  // function to select item by id out of list
  post$ = (id) => this.posts$.pipe(map(posts => posts.find(p => p.id === id)))

  getPosts() {
    // function to get remote posts
    return this.get<Post[]>('posts');
  }

  loadPosts() {
    // function to load posts and set the subject value
    this.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.postSource.next(posts));
  }
}
```

you'll have to define that `get` function and call `loadPosts` everytime you want to update the list.

Comment: Thank you, I think this solution makes the most sense and seems cleanest, and I'll give it a try here in a bit. To clarify, as I tried to explain, I really just want an Array of Posts. The Array itself should be Observable (so if any Post is added/removed/updated, it should emit a new value to subscribers, with all the current/updated posts). Then each Post in this Observable Array should also themselves be Observables, so if some client is using a specific single Post only, and then its contents are changed, the Post object should emit the update, both for itself, and the updated Array also.

Comment: it would be overly complex without clear benefit to make the type like `Observable<Array<Observable<Post>>>` when you can just leverage operators to get observables of single posts from the type `Observable<Array<Post>>` and things would be much cleaner

Comment: That was my thought as well, however, I'm just not sure of the preferred pattern to return an Observable<Post> from the Observable<Array<Post>> WITHOUT making a new Observable everytime getPostById() is called by any client. All clients should get the same Observable<Post>, right? To do that, I'd think that I would just need to cache/store the individual Posts as Observables (in the PostStore) whenever they are requested by clients... and otherwise fetch (either from existing array or server) and create a new Observable<Post> if it doesn't exist yet. Is that how it's typically done?

Comment: why are  you against creating a new observable every time? patterns involving storing observables of observables are quite uncommon

Comment: Like I said... let's say one client/component needs a specific Post, so it calls getPostById(id), and it returns an Observable<Post> (either pulled from the Observable<Array<Post>> or the server). During this operation, a new Observable<Post> would be created each time. If another client/component on the same page calls the same getPostById(id), it would be returning an entirely new Observable<Post>, and then any events emitted on either Post would not propagate to the others... I think that's how it would behave?

Comment: you're mistaken. So long as they have the same source (as in my answer and @Jonathan Stellwag's answer), every observable derived from that source via some operator will trigger when the source is triggered... in my answer, calling `next` on the `postSource` subject will trigger every observable built via the `post$` function as everything built by that function is derived from the same source

Comment: @RyanWeiss Try it for yourself, this code will fetch all posts only when the `loadPosts()` method gets called, every subsequent request for posts will be "free"

Comment: Alright guys, thank you. I will give it a shot here in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Given informations:**

*!If any of this statements is wrong, please tell me and I will update the answer!*

1. *get function that returns an observable with one array that filled with posts*
2. *the get observable emits always when the posts are changing*
3. *the value inside the observable (Array>) is no observable and does not change over time*

```
this.get<Array<Post>>('posts')
```

**Possible functions**

1. `() => getPostById$`

```
// This function returns you an observable with the post related to your id.
// If the id is not found the observable will not emit
// If the id is found the observable will only emit if the interface values have been changed
function getPostById$(id: string): Observable<Post> {
  // Returns you either the post or undefined if not found
  const findId = (id: string) => (posts: Array<Post>): Post | undefined =>
     posts.find(post => post.id === id);

  // Allows you only to emit, if id has been found
  const existingPost = (post: Post | undefined): boolean => post != null;

  // Allows you only to emit if your id has been changed
  const postComparator = (prevPost: Post, currPost: Post): boolean =>
    prevPost.value === currPost.value && prevPost.name === currPost.name;

  return this.get('posts').pipe(
    map(findId(id)),
    filter(existingPost),
    distinctUntilChanged(postComparator)
  );
}
```

2. `() => getPosts$`

```
function getPosts$(): Observable<Array<Post>> {
  return this.get('posts');
}
```

3. `() => getStatePosts$`

```
// This function allows to manage your own state
// 1. posts$: overwrites all posts
// 2. clear$: empties your posts$ observable
// 3. add$: adds one observable to the end of your posts
function statePosts$(posts$: Observable<Array<Posts>>, clear$: Observable<void>, add$: Observable<Post>): Observable<Array<Post>> {
  const updatePosts = (newPosts: Array<Posts>) => (oldPosts: Array<Posts>) => newPosts;

  const clearPosts = () => (oldPosts: Array<Posts>) => [];

  const addPost = (post: Post) => (oldPosts: Array<Posts>) => [...oldPosts, post];

  return merge(
    // You can add as much update functions as you need/want (eg: deleteId, addPostAtStart, sortPosts, ...)
    posts$.pipe(map(updatePosts)),
    clear$.pipe(map(clearPosts)),
    add$.pipe(map(addPost))
  ).pipe(
    // The fn in you scan is the (oldPosts: Array<Posts>) function from one of your three update functions (updatePosts, clearPosts and addPosts).
    // Whenever one of those three observables emits it first calls the left side of the function inside the map (post: Post) and returns a new function
    // When this function reaches the scan it gets the oldPosts and is able to update it
    scan((oldPosts, fn) => fn(oldPosts), [])
  )
}

// Usage
private posts$: Observable<Array<Post>> = this.get('posts');
private clear$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
private add$: Subject<Post> = new Subject();

public statePosts$ = getStatePosts(posts$, clear$, add$);
```

**Hint:** *Try to read the functions from the return statement first. And then check what is happening in the mapping/filtering or other operations. Hopefully I did not confuse you too much. If you have questions, feel free to ask.*

Comment: Thanks for the details! Makes some sense :) ... I know how to retrieve an Observable<Array<Post>>, but was wondering if there's a proper way for the posts themselves be Observables within the array, but maybe that's not the way to think about it... and instead should just be an Observable array of Posts (as you've illustrated), and then use the separate getPostById() function to turn the regular Posts into Observables... I just am not sure if multiple clients, calling getPostById() separately, will return completely separate Observables... then changing one won't emit the event to others... ?

Comment: I agree with the general ideas of observable state management here, but I think it'd be cleaner and more generic / reusable if you followed more of a store type model with a single action dispatch subject, that emits both a state modifying function and a payload (if needed).

Comment: Thanks. I need to read more on this pattern... I do have a store, and the store is supposed to basically just supply two things: 1) current posts array (Observable), and 2) an interface to retrieve a specific post, which should just pull it from this array, and return it as an observable.. but the observable returns should be the SAME observable that any other called would get (ie. it shouldn't make a NEW observable everything I call getPostById(id))... so trying to wrap my head around that. Maybe it's in your solution, but I need to play with it a bit.